Recursive function on finite sets - how to prove termination
I am (still) struggling with a recursive function on finite sets. I would like to define a special Cartesian product on a finite set of (finite) sets. A simplified example of what I am trying to achieve is the pcart function below:
theory Simplified
  imports Main "HOL-Library.FSet"
begin

inductive_set Fin where
  emptyI: "{} ∈ Fin" | 
  insertI: "A ∈ Fin ⟹ insert a A ∈ Fin"

lemma Fin_is_finite: "x ∈ Fin ⟹ finite x"
  using Fin.inducts by auto

lemma finite_is_Fin: "finite x ⟹ x ∈ Fin"
  by (metis Fin.simps Finp_Fin_eq finite_ne_induct)

definition ext :: "nat set ⇒ nat set set" where 
  "ext X = {{x}| x. x ∈ X}"

function pcart :: "nat set fset ⇒ nat set set" where 
  "pcart {||} = {}" | 
  "pcart (finsert a A) = ext a ∪ pcart A ∪ {{x}∪y| x y. x ∈ a ∧ y ∈ pcart A}"
  apply blast
  apply blast
  apply blast

The problem is the very last subgoal of the proof, which I have no clue how to deal with:
 ⋀a A aa Aa.
       finsert a A = finsert aa Aa ⟹
       ext a ∪ pcart_sumC A ∪ {{x} ∪ y |x y. x ∈ a ∧ y ∈ pcart_sumC A} =
       ext aa ∪ pcart_sumC Aa ∪ {{x} ∪ y |x y. x ∈ aa ∧ y ∈ pcart_sumC Aa}

My question is three folded:

Is there an easier way to define my recursive function so that I can show it terminates?
If not, is there a way to prove that my version terminates? What am I missing?
If 1 or 2 are possible, and I obtain a recursive terminating function pcart - how can I go about showing that pcart {||} = {}? I fake-terminated my current version with a sorry, then tried to use it in the simplest lemma I could think of: lemma "pcart {||} = {}". To which I get no proof. At this point, I am unsure if it's because pcart definition is flawed (I hope that's the case) or because some other issues I am unaware of.

Any suggestions will be both much appreciated and welcome.
Thank you

This is not an issue of termination. Proving termination for this function should actually be very easy. The issue here is that you have to prove the well-definedness of your function, i.e. the result does not depend on the order in which it is processed. This is because insert is not a free constructor, i.e. finsert x A = finsert y B does not mean that x = y and A = B.
I must confess that I do not really know how to do this for recursive function specifications like yours. I am not even sure it is possible. Even if it is, my recommendation would be to not define your function recursively but to find another, simpler definition and then derive the recursive equations as a corollary.
I think what you are trying to specify here is: pcart A consists of all sets X such that there is an injective function f : X → A such that f(x) ∈ x. So basically, my interpretation is that you want
pcart {{1}, {2,3}, {4,5}} =
  {{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5},
   {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4}, {1,5}, {2,4}, {2,5}, {3,4}, {4,5}, 
   {1,2,4}, {1,3,4}, {1,2,5}, {1,3,5}}

Is that what you want?
If yes, I wonder why you specified pcart {||} = {} and not pcart {||} = {{}}.
I also wonder whether you maybe meant to write:
a |∉| A ⟹ pcart (finsert a A) = ext a ∪ pcart A ∪ {{x}∪y| x y. x ∈ a ∧ y ∈ pcart A}

I do think that makes a difference.
So, if I understood correctly what you want, I would specify it like this (no need to use FSets in that case either):
definition pcart :: "nat set set ⇒ nat set set" where
  "pcart A = {X. ∃f. f ∈ X → A ∧ inj_on f X ∧ (∀x∈X. x ∈ f x)}"

With that, the following recursive specifications are provable:
lemma "pcart {} = {{}}"

lemma
  assumes "a ∉ A"
  shows "pcart (insert a A) = pcart A ∪ {insert x y |x y. x ∈ a ∧ y ∈ pcart A}"

Even if that isn't exactly what you want, I think it should be possible to tweak it so that you do get exactly what you want.

That is almost to the dot what I want! I will have to work on your definition and figure out how to tweak it - and if I don't need FSet and recursion on it, I'll be forever in your debt! Thank you for your (as usual) comprehensive and clear answer.

Great! If you have any trouble getting it right or proving those recursive equations, do feel free to ask me here or privately via email.

Oh and do note that you'll have to import HOL-Library.FuncSet for the A → B notation.

I have used choice to extract an element when I was sure that the order does not matter, but it is annoying to prove things.
